# OpenCL : retarget execution instances to perticular core at run time

Tags: opencl, embedded-linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Processor Affinity in OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476315/processor-affinity-in-opencl)
>   [OpenCL : Can we directly send a workitem to CPU core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050057/opencl-can-we-directly-send-a-workitem-to-cpu-core)

> An OpenCL application submits work to compute devices(CPU / GPU) via
>   queues. These device queues keeps kernel execution instances and sends
>   to device cores in pipeline.
>
> What I want ?
>
> I want to target this kernel execution instances to a
>   particular core (Assuming that I have multiple cores for my CPU) at
>   run time.
>
> 1.Can we capture these instances from queue and re target to
>   our targeted cores ?
>
> 2.Can it be done in OpenCL using any API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [device fission](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-device-fission-for-cpu-performance/).