# OpenCL : Targeting Work-group to a specific device

Tags: multiprocessing, opencl, cpu-architecture, gpu, multiple-gpu

Assuming that I have a multiprocessor machine. Can I bind my work-group to a specific device (processor) ?
Do we have any API to accomplish this task in openCL ?

Comment: Intel provide some level of processor affinity control in their device fission implementation, but I dont believe there isn't anything in the standard which provides that level of scheduling granularity,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something called device fission. I believe it is not supported by devices other than cpus for now.  [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476315/processor-affinity-in-opencl)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am planning to run my opencl fission code in my custom hardware.  Can I convert this to LLVM-IR ? In other words can we convert device fission code of OpenCL to LLVM IR.

Comment: I don't know about this specifically. Right now it is available for devices with drivers supporting the feature.